# css how to cancel a transition in progress

Tags: css, transition

```js
const myButt = document.getElementById('my-butt');

myButt.style.transform = 'rotate(1turn)';

myButt.addEventListener('mouseenter', function() {
  myButt.style.transition = 'transform 10s';
  
  myButt.classList.add('no');
});

myButt.addEventListener('mouseleave', function() {
  myButt.style.removeProperty('transition');
  
  myButt.style.transform = 'rotate(0turn)';
});
```

```css
#my-butt{
  width: 100px;
  height:100px;
}
.no{
  transform:  none!important;
}
```

```html
<button id="my-butt">
  over my dead butt
</button>
```

the button is initially rotated 360 degrees. When mouse over it, the button starts to rotate back to 0 degree, this takes 10 seconds. While the animation is playing, if the mouse leaves the button, the button should immediately jump to 0 degree without any further transitions.

So, in other words, I want the transition to end immediately if mouse leaves button and just jump to 0 degrees.

You can run the code snippet, it currently doesn't work.

Comment: I don't understand. When my mouse leaves the button with the code you provided, the box returns to it's initial state and doesn't transition. What do you want to happen instead?

Comment: @michael really? which browser are you using? because I'm using firefox, and the transition doesn't stop.

Comment: chrome. but looks like you figured it out? btw, you can do this in css alone. would you be interested in an answer to do that?

Comment: @Michael ah, thanks for offer. I know how to do that in css. I'm trying to animate the button when mouse enter and leave another element, that's why I need javascript. But you are right, maybe I can still do that in css... thanks for the inspiration!

Comment: Cool. this is how i would manipulate it using js http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qrLwmZ

Comment: @michael, thank you. Your code is cleaner, but I need it to have an initial  arbitrary rotation, say .8turn, then trigger it to rotate back to 0turn in 10 sec in js, then when mouse over another element, it should skip the transition and just jump to 0turn. Then when mouse leave the other element, it should go to .8turn and start rotating back to 0turn in 10 sec again.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, never mind.

Removing the `transform: none!important` class in the `mouseleave` event before setting `rotate(0turn)` seems to work.